# d3 drag and zoom not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I currently try to build a Mindmap using a d3-tree. Therefore I want to be able to drag and zoom using d3.behaviour.

The main structure of my code is based on the simple collapsible tree example by Mike Bostock.

I initialized both techniques globally before my data is loaded:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);
```

the functions are basically a copy paste of this example:
[Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)

I tried applying the zoom and drag calls after the initialization of the svg object before the loading function and outside of the update function which was not supposed to work.

Also I tried applying the functions within the update function like this `svg.call(zoom)` which is also not working. There are no errors and actually nothing is happening.

Is there something to consider when using the techniques?

### EDIT:

The functions I am using are the same as in the Example above:

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On zoomed function remember update transform property:

```
function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

and drag function update your element's position:

```
function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}
```